# Converting nested list to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, nested-lists, rbind

The goal is to convert a nested list which sometimes contain missing records into a data frame.  An example of the structure when there are missing records is:

```
mylist <- list(
  list(
    Hit = "True",
    Project = "Blue",
    Year = "2011",
    Rating = "4",
    Launch = "26 Jan 2012",
    ID = "19",
    Dept = "1, 2, 4"
  ),
  list(Hit = "False", Error = "Record not found"),
  list(
    Hit = "True",
    Project = "Green",
    Year = "2004",
    Rating = "8",
    Launch = "29 Feb 2004",
    ID = "183",
    Dept = "6, 8"
  )
)
```

When there are no missing records the list can be converted into a data frame using `data.frame(do.call(rbind.data.frame, mylist))`.  However, when records are missing this results in a column mismatch.  I know there are functions to merge data frames of non-matching columns but I'm yet to find one that can be applied to lists.  The ideal outcome would keep record 2 with NA for all variables.  Hoping for some help.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can also use (at least v1.9.3) of `rbindlist` in the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(mylist, fill=TRUE)

##      Hit Project Year Rating      Launch  ID    Dept            Error
## 1:  True    Blue 2011      4 26 Jan 2012  19 1, 2, 4               NA
## 2: False      NA   NA     NA          NA  NA      NA Record not found
## 3:  True   Green 2004      8 29 Feb 2004 183    6, 8               NA
```

Comment: [1.9.4 is now available on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) (although it may take a day more for remaining binaries to be available).

Comment: @hrbrmstr are you aware of a workaround that permits a non-uniform list structure? I'm running into `rbind/rbindlist doesn't recycle as it already expects each item to be a uniform list, data.frame or data.table`.

Comment: I get this error:
Error in data.table::rbindlist(mylist, fill = TRUE) : 
  Column 3 of item 1 is length 2 inconsistent with column 5 which is length 3. Only length-1 columns are recycled.

Comment: How about nested lists?

Answer (score 22):

You could create a list of data.frames:

```
dfs <- lapply(mylist, data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then use one of these:

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(dfs)
```

or the faster

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(dfs) # in earlier versions: rbind_all(dfs)
```

In the case of `dplyr::bind_rows`, I am surprised that it chooses to use `""` instead of `NA` for missing data. If you remove `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, you will get `NA` but at the cost of a warning... So `suppressWarnings(rbind_all(lapply(mylist, data.frame)))` would be an ugly but fast solution.

Comment: `rbind_all()` is deprecated. Please use `bind_rows()` instead.

Comment: What if in some of the rows, there is missing data for some of the columns? Just empty in the database (no NA or NULL)

Comment: I get this error:

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Answer (score 12):

I just developed a solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444968/read-json-file-into-a-data-frame-without-nested-lists/35519498#35519498) that is applicable here, so I'll provide it here as well:

```
tl <- function(e) { if (is.null(e)) return(NULL); ret <- typeof(e); if (ret == 'list' && !is.null(names(e))) ret <- list(type='namedlist') else ret <- list(type=ret,len=length(e)); ret; };
mkcsv <- function(v) paste0(collapse=',',v);
keyListToStr <- function(keyList) paste0(collapse='','/',sapply(keyList,function(key) if (is.null(key)) '*' else paste0(collapse=',',key)));

extractLevelColumns <- function(
    nodes, ## current level node selection
    ..., ## additional arguments to data.frame()
    keyList=list(), ## current key path under main list
    sep=NULL, ## optional string separator on which to join multi-element vectors; if NULL, will leave as separate columns
    mkname=function(keyList,maxLen) paste0(collapse='.',if (is.null(sep) && maxLen == 1L) keyList[-length(keyList)] else keyList) ## name builder from current keyList and character vector max length across node level; default to dot-separated keys, and remove last index component for scalars
) {
    cat(sprintf('extractLevelColumns(): %s\n',keyListToStr(keyList)));
    if (length(nodes) == 0L) return(list()); ## handle corner case of empty main list
    tlList <- lapply(nodes,tl);
    typeList <- do.call(c,lapply(tlList,`[[`,'type'));
    if (length(unique(typeList)) != 1L) stop(sprintf('error: inconsistent types (%s) at %s.',mkcsv(typeList),keyListToStr(keyList)));
    type <- typeList[1L];
    if (type == 'namedlist') { ## hash; recurse
        allKeys <- unique(do.call(c,lapply(nodes,names)));
        ret <- do.call(c,lapply(allKeys,function(key) extractLevelColumns(lapply(nodes,`[[`,key),...,keyList=c(keyList,key),sep=sep,mkname=mkname)));
    } else if (type == 'list') { ## array; recurse
        lenList <- do.call(c,lapply(tlList,`[[`,'len'));
        maxLen <- max(lenList,na.rm=T);
        allIndexes <- seq_len(maxLen);
        ret <- do.call(c,lapply(allIndexes,function(index) extractLevelColumns(lapply(nodes,function(node) if (length(node) < index) NULL else node[[index]]),...,keyList=c(keyList,index),sep=sep,mkname=mkname))); ## must be careful to translate out-of-bounds to NULL; happens automatically with string keys, but not with integer indexes
    } else if (type%in%c('raw','logical','integer','double','complex','character')) { ## atomic leaf node; build column
        lenList <- do.call(c,lapply(tlList,`[[`,'len'));
        maxLen <- max(lenList,na.rm=T);
        if (is.null(sep)) {
            ret <- lapply(seq_len(maxLen),function(i) setNames(data.frame(sapply(nodes,function(node) if (length(node) < i) NA else node[[i]]),...),mkname(c(keyList,i),maxLen)));
        } else {
            ## keep original type if maxLen is 1, IOW don't stringify
            ret <- list(setNames(data.frame(sapply(nodes,function(node) if (length(node) == 0L) NA else if (maxLen == 1L) node else paste(collapse=sep,node)),...),mkname(keyList,maxLen)));
        }; ## end if
    } else stop(sprintf('error: unsupported type %s at %s.',type,keyListToStr(keyList)));
    if (is.null(ret)) ret <- list(); ## handle corner case of exclusively empty sublists
    ret;
}; ## end extractLevelColumns()
## simple interface function
flattenList <- function(mainList,...) do.call(cbind,extractLevelColumns(mainList,...));
```

Execution:

```
## define data
mylist <- list(structure(list(Hit='True',Project='Blue',Year='2011',Rating='4',Launch='26 Jan 2012',ID='19',Dept='1, 2, 4'),.Names=c('Hit','Project','Year','Rating','Launch','ID','Dept')),structure(list(Hit='False',Error='Record not found'),.Names=c('Hit','Error')),structure(list(Hit='True',Project='Green',Year='2004',Rating='8',Launch='29 Feb 2004',ID='183',Dept='6, 8'),.Names=c('Hit','Project','Year','Rating','Launch','ID','Dept')));

## run it
df <- flattenList(mylist);
## extractLevelColumns():
## extractLevelColumns(): Hit
## extractLevelColumns(): Project
## extractLevelColumns(): Year
## extractLevelColumns(): Rating
## extractLevelColumns(): Launch
## extractLevelColumns(): ID
## extractLevelColumns(): Dept
## extractLevelColumns(): Error

df;
##     Hit Project Year Rating      Launch   ID    Dept            Error
## 1  True    Blue 2011      4 26 Jan 2012   19 1, 2, 4             <NA>
## 2 False    <NA> <NA>   <NA>        <NA> <NA>    <NA> Record not found
## 3  True   Green 2004      8 29 Feb 2004  183    6, 8             <NA>
```

My function is more powerful than `data.table::rbindlist()` as of 1.9.6, in that it can handle any number of nesting levels and different vector lengths across branches. In the linked question, my function correctly flattens the OP's list to a data.frame, but `data.table::rbindlist()` fails with `"Error in rbindlist(jsonRList, fill = T) : Column 4 of item 16 is length 2, inconsistent with first column of that item which is length 1. rbind/rbindlist doesn't recycle as it already expects each item to be a uniform list, data.frame or data.table"`.

Comment: Wow, finally I found a solution to flatten the type of list I'm facing. Thank you.

Comment: tried this on a complicated list and got: `Error in extractLevelColumns(lapply(nodes, function(node) if (length(node) <  : 
  error: inconsistent types () at /V1/2.`

Comment: @GabrielFair (and @dca) If you post a link to your list (e.g. on GitHub) I might be able to debug and improve my code to handle your list, or at least improve the error message to make it more descriptive/clearer.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I should have been more clear. I'm getting the same error you are getting at the bottom of your post where you say you can't flatten OP's list. I'll create a new SO question, If I can't get this working on my own. Thanks again

Comment: I also get an error: `Error in extractLevelColumns(lapply(nodes, `[[`, key), ..., keyList = c(keyList,  : 
  error: inconsistent types `

Comment: Will you please write a whole package for flattening things? This is fantastic, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that converts any nested/uneven list to dataframe. `rbindlist` doesn't work for many cases, especially for list of lists. So I had to create something better than `rbindlist`.

```
rbindlist.v2 <- function(l)
{
   l <- l[lapply(l, class) == "list"]
   df <- foreach(element = l, .combine = bind_rows, .errorhandling = 'remove') %do%
         {df = unlist(element); df = as.data.frame(t(df)); rm(element); return(df)}
   rm(l)
   return(df)
}
```

For large lists you can expedite the process by replacing `%do%` to `%dopar%`. That was also something I needed for my case.

Comment: This is a really cool function. Could you please kindly explain how the function works? I tried to understand how it works, but it is not exactly straightforward for me.

Comment: Where is the `%do%` function defined?

Comment: The `%do%`-operator seems to come from the library `foreach`. Anyway, the code doesn't work in my case -- it generates one row with > 489.000 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative @ishonest:

```
df <- purrr::map_dfr(l,function(y){
  y[[1]]
})
```

here are some other methods that depend on how the lists are nested:

list of lists

```
df <- purrr::map_dfr(r,function(x){
    unlist(x)
})
```

if the nested list is more complex, where some elements are lists:

```
format_json_list <- function(r){
  purrr::map_dfr(r,function(x){
    #Base object, e.g. Vessel info
    b <- x[[1]]
    # object's events, e.g. paces Vessel visited 
    df <- purrr::map_dfr(x[[2]],function(y){
        v <- y[[1]]
        p <- y[2:length(y)]
        dplyr::bind_cols(v,p)
    })
    dplyr::bind_cols(b,df)
  })
}
```

for some complex json, duplicate variable naming can be an issue. One fix is to specify the naming. This code below is the hard coding the names. I recon this can be made dynamic.

```
purrr::map_dfr(vo, function(vessels){
      if(is.list(vessels)){
        vinfo <- purrr::map_dfr(vessels, function(vessel){
          if(!is.list(vessel)){
            #print(vessel)
            vessel
          }
        }) %>%  dplyr::rename_all(~ paste0("Vessel.", .))
        calinfo <- purrr::map_dfr(vessels$Callings, function(calling){
          if(is.list(calling)){
            call <- purrr::map_dfr(calling, function(call){
              if(!is.list(call)){
                call
              }
            })
            callport <- purrr::map_dfr(calling$Port, function(port){
              if(!is.list(port)){
                port
              }
            }) %>% dplyr::rename_all(~ paste0("Port.", .))
            dplyr::bind_cols(call, callport)
          }
        }) %>%  dplyr::rename_all(~ paste0("Calling.", .))
        bind_cols(vinfo, calinfo)
      } 
    }, .id ="Vessel" ) 
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you like `purrr`:

```
> te <- list(structure(list(Hit = "True", Project = "Blue", Year = "2011", 
Rating = "4", Launch = "26 Jan 2012", ID = "19", Dept = "1, 2, 4"), .Names = c("Hit", "Project", "Year", "Rating", "Launch", "ID", "Dept")), structure(list(
Hit = "False", Error = "Record not found"), .Names = c("Hit", 
"Error")), structure(list(Hit = "True", Project = "Green", Year = "2004", 
Rating = "8", Launch = "29 Feb 2004", ID = "183", Dept = "6, 8"), .Names = c("Hit", "Project", "Year", "Rating", "Launch", "ID", "Dept")))

> str(te)
List of 3
 $ :List of 7
  ..$ Hit    : chr "True"
  ..$ Project: chr "Blue"
  ..$ Year   : chr "2011"
  ..$ Rating : chr "4"
  ..$ Launch : chr "26 Jan 2012"
  ..$ ID     : chr "19"
  ..$ Dept   : chr "1, 2, 4"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ Hit  : chr "False"
  ..$ Error: chr "Record not found"
 $ :List of 7
  ..$ Hit    : chr "True"
  ..$ Project: chr "Green"
  ..$ Year   : chr "2004"
  ..$ Rating : chr "8"
  ..$ Launch : chr "29 Feb 2004"
  ..$ ID     : chr "183"
  ..$ Dept   : chr "6, 8"
> purrr::map_dfr(te,as_tibble)
# A tibble: 3 × 8
  Hit   Project Year  Rating Launch      ID    Dept    Error           
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>       <chr> <chr>   <chr>           
1 True  Blue    2011  4      26 Jan 2012 19    1, 2, 4 NA              
2 False NA      NA    NA     NA          NA    NA      Record not found
3 True  Green   2004  8      29 Feb 2004 183   6, 8    NA
```