# R: How to convert a nested JSON to dataframe

Tags: r, json

I have nested JSON (lines) file which looks like

```
[{"ok":2, "nested": {"meh":2, "hehe":{"a":1, "b":2 }}},
{"ok":3, "nested": {"meh":10, "hehe":{"a":1, "b":2}}},
{"ok":4, "nested": {"meh":11, "hehe":{"a":1, "b":2}}}]
...
```

and I wish to unnest it into the data.frame represented CSV form

```
ok, nested.meh, nested.hehe.a, nested.hehe.b
2, 2, 1, 2
3, 10, 1, 2
4, 11, 1, 2
...
```

I tried

```
a = jsonlite::read_json("file.json")
```

But then a list of list, which seems to need custom coding to unnest, but I want to read general nested files. Is there a package to handle this? I looked through the documentation for `rlist` but couldn't find info as `rlist::table` didn't work.

Comment: check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444968/read-json-file-into-a-data-frame-without-nested-lists

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
a = jsonlite::fromJSON("file.json", flatten = TRUE)
```

I created `file.json` by pasting the below into a blank Notepad++ text document. Sometimes my issues importing `json` files into `R` have been because of text formatting issues, so also double check original file for errant whitespace or other characters.

## Data

```
[{"ok":2, "nested": {"meh":2, "hehe":{"a":1, "b":2 }}},
{"ok":3, "nested": {"meh":10, "hehe":{"a":1, "b":2}}},
{"ok":4, "nested": {"meh":11, "hehe":{"a":1, "b":2}}}]
```

Comment: Have you called `str(a)`? What I'm getting *looks* like a flat data frame, but a little investigation shows it's actually the type of nested list the OP is describing

Comment: oops, forgot to add `flatten = TRUE`, editing

Answer (score 0):

I usually go for the flatten_json package

```
import flatten_json

ex_json = [{"ok":2, "nested": {"meh":2, "hehe":{"a":1, "b":2 }}},
{"ok":3, "nested": {"meh":10, "hehe":{"a":1, "b":2}}},
{"ok":4, "nested": {"meh":11, "hehe":{"a":1, "b":2}}}]

ex_df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(flatten_json.flatten_json(ex_json[0], separator="."))
```

Comment: That's Python; this question is about R

Comment: Oh gosh you're right, whoops!