# convert data frames in nested lists to large data frame

Tags: r

I have a large nested List with 3 levels:
the elements are data frames with the same name.

List:

```
[[1]]

[[1]][[1]]

[[1]][[1]][[1]]

"name1" "name2" "name3" "name4" "name5"

numeric1 numeric2 string3 string4 string5

[[1]][[1]][[2]]

"name1" "name2" "name3" "name4" "name5"

numeric1 numeric2 string3 string4 string5

[[1]][[1]][[3]]

"name1" "name2" "name3" "name4" "name5"

numeric1 numeric2 string3 string4 string5
```

How I can rbind all data frames to one large data frame?

manually it works this way:
    rbind(list[[1]][[1]][[1]], list[[1]][[1]][[2]],....)

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: (Why we need a reproducible example?)  Because it's unclear whether your list has all of its values in the first sub-sublist of the first sublist. Might be a simple as `do.call(rbind, listName[[1]][[1]] )`, .... but maybe not.

Comment: @dom Take a look at this [Converting nested list to dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177565/converting-nested-list-to-dataframe)

Answer (score -3):

ldply(do.call("c",do.call("c",list)), data.frame)

Comment: Your answer would benefit immensely if you added some comment about what your code is doing and proof that this is indeed the correct solution.