# Reading an excel array with missing values into R using BERT interface

Tags: r, excel, missing-data, bert-toolkit

I am using BERT (Excel/R interface) to implement R functions into Excel. When a function such as eigen is applied to an array of numbers it works fine, but there is an error if there are missing value / strings in the Excel array. I want to remove, in the R function - not in Excel - the columns (or rows) of the array that have non numeric data. The problem of course is that BERT gives to R a matrix when the array has only numbers but a list if there are non numeric data in the Excel array. So basically I want to change that R list into the equivalent R dataframe with missing values at the right places.

So if in EXCEL I have

```
1 2
3 4
```

In the range (A1:B2) then I define this function in R.

```
EigenValues <- function(mat) { 
  print(mat)
  print(mode(mat))
  E<- eigen(mat)
  E$values
 }
```

In Excel this works just fine and the R console shows me that     mat is a matrix.
If in cell A1 in Excel I have a blank value, then R describes mat as follows :

```
[,1] [,2]
[1,] NA 2   
[2,] 3  4   
[1] "list"
```

An obviously I get an error in Excel. So I would like to to remove the rows (or columns) where I have an NA. I have searched a lot and found nothing that works with that kind of list. E.g. this, [Converting nested list to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177565/converting-nested-list-to-dataframe), using the rbind.list function, does not work.

Using     dplyr and     rbind_all does not work either. I suspect this is because I have different number of missing values in each row or column.

This [How to convert a list consisting of vector of different lengths to a usable data frame in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201305/how-to-convert-a-list-consisting-of-vector-of-different-lengths-to-a-usable-data) does not work because the missing values are not necessarily at the end of each row.

```
rbind.fill(Reduce(unlist, mat))
```

will produce only a single NA.

Answer (score 1):

If one of the matrix elements contains bad data (`NA` value or missing data), then *BERT* coerces the input matrix into a list. 
But the input list still has a `dim` attribute, so it's possible to coerce it back into a matrix.  Then you can remove the rows and columns containing bad data using the function `complete.cases()`.  The following function worked for me:

```
EigenValues <- function(mat) {
  mat <- matrix(unlist(mat), nrow=dim(mat)[1])
  complete_rows <- complete.cases(mat)
  complete_cols <- complete.cases(t(mat))
  mat <- mat[t(complete_rows), t(complete_cols)]
  E <- eigen(mat)
  E$values
}
```