# Convert list of list object to dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of list as given below. ANd I want to convert it into dataframe in the desired format.

myList:

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[[2]]$`file`
[1] "ABC"

[[2]]$New
[1] 21

[[2]]$Old
[1] 42


[[3]]
[[3]]$`file`
[1] "CDF"

[[3]]$NEW
[1] 206

[[3]]$Old
[1] 84
```

And I want to convert this list of list object to dataframe in the desired format:

```
file   New   Old
ABC    21     42
CDF    206    84
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RichScriven, thanks it worked and from next time I will put reproducible example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - list to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame)

Comment: Not quite.  This is a nested list.

Comment: @RichScriven check **Ian Sudbery** answer's

Comment: Sure. If you like long, complicated code.

Comment: [Converting nested list to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177565/converting-nested-list-to-dataframe)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like (`ls` is your list):

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(ls), ncol = max(lengths(ls)), byrow = TRUE))
```

If column names matter, then

```
names(df) <- names(ls[[which(lengths(ls)>0)[1]]])
```

Comment: `Warning message:
In matrix(unlist(myLIST), ncol = max(lengths(myLIST)), byrow = TRUE) :
  data length [20000] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [1000]`

Answer (score 21):

We can use `map_df` after converting to a `tibble`

```
library(tidyverse)
myList %>% 
   map_df(as_tibble)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  file    New   Old
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 ABC      21    42
#2 CDF     206    84
```

Or with `bind_rows`

```
bind_rows(myList)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  file    New   Old
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 ABC      21    42
#2 CDF     206    84
```

#### data

```
myList <- list(NULL, list(file = 'ABC', New = 21, Old = 42), 
                      list(file = 'CDF', New = 206, Old = 84))
```

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the following would work.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(list, as.data.frame))
```

where `list` is your list.

Comment: `Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0`