# How to import a dynamodb table attribute into a dataframe in R and plot the dataframe using ggplot

Tags: r, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to import dynamodb in R using paws.database library. I am successful in retrieving the required attribute into R(using scan operation). However the imported data is in the form of a nested list i.e. in [[]] form. My intention is to format the imported dynamodb attribute into a dataframe and later be able to plot it using ggpplot. I have tried using options such as

- df <- ldply (list_a, data.frame), ldply (list_a, data.frame),
- data.frame(matrix(unlist(list_a),  nrow=length(list_a),
  byrow=TRUE),stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,list_a))

so far and was unable to convert the data in a proper dataframe format. The final error I get in ggplot is ***"
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a list "***

Could anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

[See this similar issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177565/converting-nested-list-to-dataframe)

I'm also using paws. Here's what I did to work with a small DynamoDB table:

```
dyna <- paws::dynamodb()

Table<-dyna$scan("table_name")

newtable<-rbindlist(Table$Items,fill = TRUE)
```

Then I create a new dataframe by using unlist() on each column of *newtable*.