# Convert 3 level nested list with vectors into dataframe

Tags: r, datatable

My source data looks like this:

```
data <- list(row1 = list(D = data.table(stat = "D", est = 0.2), HM = data.table(stat = c("H","M"), est = c(0.4,0.5))),
             row2 = list(D = data.table(stat = "D", est = 0.3), HM = data.table(stat = c("H","M"), est = c(0.1,0.6))))
```

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I apply some solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177565/converting-nested-list-to-dataframe), for de-nesting lists, for example:

```
as.data.frame(t(sapply(data, unlist)))
```

But I get:

[image]

Seems like I could do one more step and try to manually clean the latter, but the actual data is more populous and with more variables. I thought I needed to first reconvert doubles (vectors) into singles but after that result is the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a clunky solution using `dplyr::bind_rows()`.

Use `lapply()` to bind the sublists together and then row_bind the parent lists together.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(lapply(data, bind_rows))

  stat est
1    D 0.2
2    H 0.4
3    M 0.5
4    D 0.3
5    H 0.1
6    M 0.6
```

This will work for list which are 2 level deep, if it is 3 levels deep, then another lapply() is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you just need to flatten the list and row bind:

```
library(data.table) # your example data contains data tables
do.call(rbind, unlist(data, recursive = FALSE))
   stat est
1:    D 0.2
2:    H 0.4
3:    M 0.5
4:    D 0.3
5:    H 0.1
6:    M 0.6
```

Or with `data.table::rbindlist()`

```
rbindlist(unlist(data, recursive = FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks. Accepted the other just because has lower reputation but both worked!