# Is there a way to convert lists(containing sublist) into dataframe in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to

```
df <- list(historicalStockList = 
               list(list(symbol = "Com1", historical = list(
                   list(date = "2024-02-20", open = 27.95, high = 27.95, low = 26.01, 
                        close = 26.1, adjClose = 26.1, volume = 398411, unadjustedVolume = 385421, 
                        change = -1.85, changePercent = -6.62, vwap = 26.49, 
                        label = "February 20, 24", changeOverTime = -0.0662), 
                   list(date = "2024-02-16", open = 29.77, high = 31.43, low = 27.17, 
                        close = 28, adjClose = 28, volume = 912267, unadjustedVolume = 912100, 
                        change = -1.77, changePercent = -5.95, vwap = 28.51, 
                        label = "February 16, 24", changeOverTime = -0.0595))), 
                   list(symbol = "Com2", historical = list(
                       list(date = "2024-02-20", open = 469.715, high = 476.18, 
                            low = 466.56, close = 471.75, adjClose = 471.75, volume = 17972319, 
                            unadjustedVolume = 17922990, change = 2.035, changePercent = 0.43324, 
                            vwap = 470.71, label = "February 20, 24", changeOverTime = 0.0043324), 
                       list(date = "2024-02-16", open = 478.11, high = 478.96, low = 469.21, 
                            close = 473.32, adjClose = 473.32, volume = 22799620, 
                            unadjustedVolume = 23306500, change = -4.79, changePercent = -1, 
                            vwap = 474.06, label = "February 16, 24", changeOverTime = -0.01)))))
```

I tried with following code but not able to get it

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, df)
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  row names supplied are of the wrong length
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177565/converting-nested-list-to-dataframe

Comment: Did either of you (@GrzegorzSapijaszko @jdobres) try those approaches? `rbindlist` errors, `purrr::map_dfr` and `bind_rows` return an arbitrarily-nested frame (which doesn't resolve easily). The `rbindlist.v2` produces a single row where the data to me strongly suggests it should have 4 rows.

Comment: You are right @r2evans, I haven't tried it. Just from looking through that answer it seemed promising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%  
  pluck("historicalStockList") %>%  
  map_dfr(~ as_tibble(.x) %>% 
            unnest_wider(historical))

# A tibble: 4 × 14
  symbol date        open  high   low close adjClose   volume unadjustedVolume change changePercent  vwap label           changeOverTime
  <chr>  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>            <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                    <dbl>
1 Com1   2024-02-20  28.0  28.0  26.0  26.1     26.1   398411           385421  -1.85        -6.62   26.5 February 20, 24       -0.0662 
2 Com1   2024-02-16  29.8  31.4  27.2  28       28     912267           912100  -1.77        -5.95   28.5 February 16, 24       -0.0595 
3 Com2   2024-02-20 470.  476.  467.  472.     472.  17972319         17922990   2.04         0.433 471.  February 20, 24        0.00433
4 Com2   2024-02-16 478.  479.  469.  473.     473.  22799620         23306500  -4.79        -1     474.  February 16, 24       -0.01
```

Noticed that `map_dfr` is [superseded](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map_dfr.html), therefore:

```
df %>%  
  pluck("historicalStockList") %>%  
  map(~ as_tibble(.x) %>% 
            unnest_wider(historical)) %>% 
  list_rbind()
```

Comment: thanks. But i get this error ````Error in list_rbind(.) : could not find function "list_rbind"````

Comment: install `tidyverse`, or update it to the latest version

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Use a nested `bind_rows` as shown

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(lapply(df[[1]], \(x) cbind(x[1], bind_rows(x[[2]]))))
```

giving

```
  symbol       date    open   high    low  close adjClose   volume
1   Com1 2024-02-20  27.950  27.95  26.01  26.10    26.10   398411
2   Com1 2024-02-16  29.770  31.43  27.17  28.00    28.00   912267
3   Com2 2024-02-20 469.715 476.18 466.56 471.75   471.75 17972319
4   Com2 2024-02-16 478.110 478.96 469.21 473.32   473.32 22799620
  unadjustedVolume change changePercent   vwap           label changeOverTime
1           385421 -1.850      -6.62000  26.49 February 20, 24     -0.0662000
2           912100 -1.770      -5.95000  28.51 February 16, 24     -0.0595000
3         17922990  2.035       0.43324 470.71 February 20, 24      0.0043324
4         23306500 -4.790      -1.00000 474.06 February 16, 24     -0.0100000
```

**2)** An alternative is to use tibblify

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibblify)

unnest(tibblify(df[[1]]), historical)
```

giving

```
# A tibble: 4 × 14
  symbol date    open  high   low close adjClose volume unadjustedVolume change
  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>            <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Com1   2024-…  28.0  28.0  26.0  26.1     26.1 3.98e5           385421  -1.85
2 Com1   2024-…  29.8  31.4  27.2  28       28   9.12e5           912100  -1.77
3 Com2   2024-… 470.  476.  467.  472.     472.  1.80e7         17922990   2.04
4 Com2   2024-… 478.  479.  469.  473.     473.  2.28e7         23306500  -4.79
# ℹ 4 more variables: changePercent <dbl>, vwap <dbl>, label <chr>,
#   changeOverTime <dbl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not supply desired output, i guessed this is what you are looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
ans <- dplyr::bind_rows(unlist(df,recursive = FALSE))
final <- cbind(ans, dplyr::bind_rows(ans$historical))
final$historical <- NULL
final
  symbol       date    open   high    low  close adjClose   volume unadjustedVolume change changePercent   vwap           label changeOverTime
1   Com1 2024-02-20  27.950  27.95  26.01  26.10    26.10   398411           385421 -1.850      -6.62000  26.49 February 20, 24     -0.0662000
2   Com1 2024-02-16  29.770  31.43  27.17  28.00    28.00   912267           912100 -1.770      -5.95000  28.51 February 16, 24     -0.0595000
3   Com2 2024-02-20 469.715 476.18 466.56 471.75   471.75 17972319         17922990  2.035       0.43324 470.71 February 20, 24      0.0043324
4   Com2 2024-02-16 478.110 478.96 469.21 473.32   473.32 22799620         23306500 -4.790      -1.00000 474.06 February 16, 24     -0.0100000
```